# terraform azurerm : Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli, azure-rm

When trying to run terraform locally with azurerm provider on my machine, I receive this error :

> Error: Error building account: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1

I followed this link : 
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3686#issuecomment-523983734

but the `az account get-access-token` works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Since my organization is using a self-signed certificate to control internet traffic, the az cli is not working as usual. To diagnose, you should run this command :

`az ad signed-in-user show`

It will show you a very clear message to workaround this issue.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#working-behind-a-proxy

I exported the CA certificate from any website from Chrome in Base64 and copied the string in the pem file as indicated in the previous link. It worked!

On Windows :
Append the certificate in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Very good hint! `az ad signed-in-user show` showed that my token has expired and I need to `az login` again.

Answer (score 3):

Run `az login` again, it's worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer is very similar to the others, the only thing that worked for my was to run:

```
$ az logout
```

Then:

```
$ az login
```

Just but running the login command, didn't seem to do anything. But by logging out I suspect it cleaned up any cache etc, then logging in after that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this but the `az ad signed-in-user show` worked and the Azure CLI was up-to-date.

Terraform uses the command-line under-the-hood, but my terminal had additional lines injected in at the start (versioning, aliases/doskey), which is the bit that terraform was complaining about, rather than the Azure CLI. So I turned that off and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. After looking through the link you provided, and trying various commands, including `az logout` and `az login`, it still was not working. `az ad signed-in-user show` did not show any errors or non-json output and my token was not expired, however when I ran `az extension --help`, I noticed a message that there was an update available for the azure cli.

So, what ended up working for me was to update the azure cli from `2.41.0` to `2.42.0`. I did this via Homebrew, rather than the command given by the cli itself. Once I did that and then ran `az login` again, my `terraform plan` command worked without issues.