# terraform azurerm : ERROR : exit status 1 - az login required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

providers.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

terraform version: `Terraform v1.1.7`

terraform command: `terraform plan`

**CLI Error**:

```
Error: building AzureRM Client: obtain subscription(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX) from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

 
   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
   on providers.tf line 10, in provider "azurerm":
   10: provider "azurerm" {
```

I did run `az login` and signed into my Azure account.

---

**Question:**

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does your account have access to that tenant and the subscription? What rights do you have on that subscription? If you run az account list what account are you in? 

Also why are you putting the tenant and sub values in the provider it’s not really needed to the CLI commands only when your using a service principle.

Comment: Hi @Jason Yes it does. I've got owner rights. 

az account list - I'm connected to a bunch of accounts. I can confirm however I'm connected to the correct account with matching sub and tenant id.

Comment: So comment out the tenant I’d and subscription part then run all the terraform commands. Terraform Init. Let me know what happens.

Comment: I've done so. Same result.

Comment: Have you considered the solution of [Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60838569/846163) by executing `az ad signed-in-user show`? To gather more information, you can run Terraform with `TF_LOG=DEBUG` environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried running "az logout" multiple times until you see "There are no active accounts", running "az login", "az account set -s <your-subscription-name>", then  re-running "terraform init" and finally, "terraform plan"?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my environment getting the same error when i haven't connected with any active account.

[image]

As Suggested by [cdub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11611377/cdub) is correct , Tried running `az logout` multiple times until you see ***There are no active accounts***, running `az login`, `az account set -s <your-subscription-name>`, then re-running `terraform init` and finally, `terraform plan`

```
#get the current default subscription using show
az account show --output table
```

[image]